# Start point for filtering data

Tags: python, algorithm, filter

I have been recording sports data - time to swim 25m lengths on my smart watch, however it is not that reliable. So given that it is usually about 40s to do one length:

1. sometimes my watch thinks I have turned around in the middle and gives multiple values that add up to the ~40s
2. sometimes misses the turn around and gives me a value greater than ~40s
3. Sometimes gets it wrong and I get a 30s and a 50s which is wrong

I am looking for an algorithm to try and correct the data but I dont know where to start. Can anyone point me towards a strategy for trying to solve this. I have thought about taking the average to give me a target value and then doing some kind of best fit, but I cant find a neat way to do this, especially as the typical leg length is variable. I am most likley to code the solution in python when I am done.

I welcome any pointers as to ways to solve this!

An example data set looks like:

"00:36.1, 00:31.6, 00:34.6, 00:38.4, 00:38.8, 00:37.9, 00:13.2, 00:25.1, 00:37, 00:40.3, 00:38.6, 00:39.8, 00:40.1, 00:42.9, 00:20.8, 00:18.9, 00:38.8, 00:39.5, 00:41.7, 00:37.4, 00:36.6, 00:41.8, 00:38.5, 00:41.8, 00:42.4, 00:38.9, 00:41.9, 00:38.8, 00:40.1, 00:39.6, 00:42.8, 00:31, 00:52.5, 00:40.1, 00:41.4, 00:26.8, 00:16.3, 00:43.9, 00:43.9, 00:42.1, 00:40.8, 00:42.4, 00:44.4, 00:42, 00:42.3, 00:13.9, 00:31.6, 00:41.9, 00:45.7, 01:12.2, 00:14.1, 00:42.6, 00:42.8, 00:41.3, 00:45, 00:21.9, 00:21.9, 00:28.9, 00:16.2, 00:43.5, 00:43.9, 00:28.4, 00:15.1, 00:44.6, 00:40.3, 00:24.8, 00:15.5, 00:44.1, 00:41.6, 00:41.7, 00:24.9, 00:15.6, 00:28.4, 00:17.3, 00:39.9, 00:42.3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a *very* simplified error correction - it checks for deviations from median, for both pairs and single values. Before (blue) and after (orange) + median (red):

[image]

```
import numpy as np

t = "00:36.1, 00:31.6, 00:34.6, 00:38.4, 00:38.8, 00:37.9, 00:13.2, 00:25.1, 00:37, 00:40.3, 00:38.6, 00:39.8, 00:40.1, 00:42.9, 00:20.8, 00:18.9, 00:38.8, 00:39.5, 00:41.7, 00:37.4, 00:36.6, 00:41.8, 00:38.5, 00:41.8, 00:42.4, 00:38.9, 00:41.9, 00:38.8, 00:40.1, 00:39.6, 00:42.8, 00:31, 00:52.5, 00:40.1, 00:41.4, 00:26.8, 00:16.3, 00:43.9, 00:43.9, 00:42.1, 00:40.8, 00:42.4, 00:44.4, 00:42, 00:42.3, 00:13.9, 00:31.6, 00:41.9, 00:45.7, 01:12.2, 00:14.1, 00:42.6, 00:42.8, 00:41.3, 00:45, 00:21.9, 00:21.9, 00:28.9, 00:16.2, 00:43.5, 00:43.9, 00:28.4, 00:15.1, 00:44.6, 00:40.3, 00:24.8, 00:15.5, 00:44.1, 00:41.6, 00:41.7, 00:24.9, 00:15.6, 00:28.4, 00:17.3, 00:39.9, 00:42.3"
t = np.array([float(i[3:]) for i in t.split(', ')])
median = np.median(t)

tolerance = 0.2 * median

t2 = []
skip = False
for i in range(len(t)-1):
    if skip:
        skip = False
        continue
        
    prv, nxt = t[i], t[i+1]

    if abs(prv-median)>tolerance and abs(nxt-median)>tolerance:
        if min(prv, nxt) < median and max(prv, nxt) > median:
            val = (prv+nxt)/2
        elif prv < median and nxt < median:
            val = prv + nxt
        t2.append(val)
        skip = True
    elif abs(prv-median)>tolerance and prv > median:
        t2.extend([prv/2]*2)
    else:
        t2.append(prv)
```

You can play with it further, it's a place to start :)

Comment: Thank you - this looks like a very helpful start point - I will have a play and let you know how I get on!

Comment: @ChrisHughes any updates?

Comment: Sorry for a slow answer! This really helped!